# .ksh paste user input value into dataset

Tags: unix, ksh, paste

Good morning.

First things first: I know next to nothing about shell scripting in Unix, so please pardon my naivety.

Here's what I'd like to do, and I *think* it's relatively simple:  I would like to create a .ksh file to do two things: 1) take a user-provided numerical value (argument) and paste it into a new column at the end of a dataset (a separate .txt file), and 2) execute a different .ksh script.

I envision calling this script at the Unix prompt, with the input value added thereafter.  Something like, "paste_and_run.ksh 58", where 58 would populate a new, final (un-headered) column in an existing dataset (specifically, it'd populate the 77th column).

To be perfectly honest, I'm not even sure where to start with this, so any input would be very appreciated. Apologies for the lack of code within the question.  Please let me know if I can offer any more detail, and thank you for taking a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer: the "nawk" command.

```
TheNumber=$3
PE_Infile=$1
```

Where the above variables correspond to the third and first arguments from the command line, respectively.  "PE_Infile" represents the file (with full path) to be manipulated, and "TheNumber" represents the number to populate the final column.  Then:

```
nawk -F"|" -v TheNewNumber=$TheNumber '{print $0 "|" TheNewNumber/10000}' $PE_Infile > $BinFolder/Temp_Input.txt
```

Here, the -F"|" dictates the delimiter, and the -v dictates what is to be added.  For reasons unknown to myself, the declaration of a new varible (TheNewNumber) was necessary to perform the arithmetic manipulation within the print statement.  print $0 means that the whole line would be printed, while tacking the "|" symbol and the value of the command line input divided by 10000 to the end.  Finally, we have the input file and an output file (Temp_PE_Input.txt, within a path represented by the $Binfolder variable).

Running the desired script afterward was as simple as typing out the script name (with path), and adding corresponding arguments ($2 $3) afterward as needed, each separated by a space.